# Regex for finding groups in One FishTwo FishRed FishBlue Fish

Tags: regex

I'm trying to gather the groups of words in a string. The string might be names, but using this familiar text as my example:

One FishTwo FishRed FishBlue Fish

the goal is to find groups of capitalized phrases: (One Fish) (Two Fish) (Red Fish) (Blue Fish), where each group is in parentheses.

```
(\w+\s[A-Z]\w+)
```

this will find this group: (One FishTwo) FishRed FishBlue Fish

How do I capture each set of capitalized words?

Comment: Can you limit the groups by something else?  According to your example, I see many more groups than just what you highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second part, you must use `[A-Z][a-z]+`, since `\w+` matches both upper and lowercase letters.

```
[A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z][a-z]+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bH6yT0/5)

Comment: that's the one! thanks. I was using RegExr to test. (\w+\s\w+(?=[A-Z])) was not capturing all the groups in the string properly.

Comment: So If I wanted to capture a three word group like  <br/>"One Fish Red"   from "One Fish RedTwo Fish Blue"   this would be be ([A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z][a-z]*) But what if my string contains both groupings?  "One Fish RedBlue Fish"  so that it can find "One Fish Red" and "Blue Fish"  tried ([A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)|([A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)

Answer (score 1):

or this pattern

```
((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s?){2})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/233)